# Mocking async methods with optional parameters throws Expression is not a Property Access

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm using the Nuget package Moq (v4.13.1)

The class/method I'm trying to mock has the following interface:

```
public interface IAgendaService
{
    Task<IList<IMeeting>> GetRecentMeetingsMostRecentFirstAsync(
        IWho who,
        TimeSpan? timeSpan = null,
        int? maxNumberOfMeetings = null);
}
```

In my test method I have the following code to define the Mock:

```
        Mock<IAgendaService> service = new Mock<IAgendaService>(MockBehavior.Strict);

        service.SetupGet(x =>
                x.GetRecentMeetingsMostRecentFirstAsync(
                    It.IsAny<IWho>(),
                    It.IsAny<TimeSpan?>(),
                    It.IsAny<int?>()))
            .Returns(Task.FromResult((IList<IMeeting>)new List<IMeeting>()));
```

When I run the test, the service.SetupGet() throws the following exception:

Test method Agenda.Web.Tests.Controllers.HomeController.IndexTests.TestIndex threw exception: 
System.ArgumentException: Expression is not a property access: x => x.GetRecentMeetingsMostRecentFirstAsync(It.IsAny(), It.IsAny(), It.IsAny())
    at Moq.ExpressionExtensions.ToPropertyInfo(LambdaExpression expression)
   at Moq.Mock.SetupGet(Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Condition condition)
   at Moq.Mock`1.SetupGet[TProperty](Expression`1 expression)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to use `service.Setup()` method no `SetupGet`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you are using the wrong method to do the mock setup. You should be using the `Setup` method as `SetupGet` is used for property getter. Try following:

```
service.Setup(x =>
            x.GetRecentMeetingsMostRecentFirstAsync(
                It.IsAny<IWho>(),
                It.IsAny<TimeSpan?>(),
                It.IsAny<int?>()))
        .Returns((IList<IMeeting>)new List<IMeeting>()));
```

There is also no need to use `Task.FromResult` as there is nothing async happening as it's a mock object.